# Замена фрагмента на фрагмент

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть фрагмент `Fragment1`, на него с помощью `RecyclerView` выводятся `Button` в адаптере это выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder,final int position){
    final Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    final int id = (listItems.get(position).getId());
    holder.button.setText(listItems.get(position).getName());
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.button:
                            fragment1.replaceFragment(id);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
        });
}
```

Метод `replaceFragment()` прописан в классе `Fragment1` используется для определения нажатой кнопки и замещения `Fragment1` на `Fragment2`, `Fragment3` и т.д. Выглядит это так:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
private List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
private Context context;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pb_layout,null);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(listItems, getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}

public void replaceFragment(int id){
    fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    switch (id){
        case 1:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Fragment2()).commit();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Fragment3()).commit();
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}}
```

Вроде должно работать но выбивает ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
```

В строке: `fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина.

Comment: От чего наследуются у вас активити и фрагмент?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб активити от AppCompatActivity, а фрагмент от Fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете фрагмент:

```
Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
```

После этого в переменной `fragment1` хранится ссылка на созданный фрагмент, **который еще не привязан ни к какой активити** (у этого фрагмента нет хоста в виде активити).

Далее Вы вызываете метод фрагмента:

```
fragment1.replaceFragment(id);
```

В котором, в частности, происходит получение `FragmentManager`'а:

```
fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Метод `getFragmentManager()` класса `Fragment` возвращает `FragmentManager` активити, которая является хостом для данного фрагмента.

Так как данный фрагмент не связан ни с какой активити, то метод `getFragmentManager()` возвращает `null` и далее происходит вызов **нестатического** метода на `null`-объекте, в результате чего и генерируется `NullPointerException`.

Вообще не очень понятно: если у Вас `RecyclerView` находится во фрагменте `Fragment1`, то зачем в адаптере Вы создаете новый инстанс `Fragment1`? Взаимодействуйте непосредственно с тем фрагментом, в котором находится `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Я делаю это что бы вызвать метод находящийся в `Fragment1` в адаптере